# my footer is coming up when clicking on input field in mobile using ionic

Tags: android, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

[image: when clicked on input field]

[image: normal screen.]
When user is clicking on input field to put email or password my footer is coming up on the fields .

```
<div class=" bar bar-footer myfooter "> 
   <p class="login-p">Don't have an account? 
    <b class="forgot-details-link">
      <a ng-href="#/signup" ng-click="reload('signup')">Sign Up</a>
    </b> 
   </p> 
</div>
```

Css

```
.myfooter{ 
      background-color: transparent; 
      display: block; 
      position: fixed; 
      background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.07); 
      border-top: solid 1px rgba(250,250,250,0.30) 
 }
```

Comment: You can provide your code?

Comment: MY html for Footer.

<div class=" bar bar-footer myfooter ">
 <p class="login-p">Don't have an account? <b class="forgot-details-link"><a ng-href="#/signup" ng-click="reload('signup')">Sign Up</a></b> </p>
</div>
</div>

My css for footer.
.myfooter{
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.07);
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(250,250,250,0.30)
}

Comment: Please add me to your question.

Comment: how can i add you to my question?

Answer (score 0):

What I want to know is because it occupies the directives ionic delivery for you, for example in the documentation is clearly the footer in question.

```
<ion-content class="has-footer">
      Some content!
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-assertive">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button">Left Button</button>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
      <div class="buttons" ng-click="doSomething()">
        <button class="button">Right Button</button>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

If you take this structure, combined with its css, you should not have display problems. Also I suggest that modifications of these classes and added to the framework, only modify colors, text sizes, fonts, etc, since they are ready to run correctly. This is only if you occupy these directives.

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: Let me know! @Najamussaqib

Answer (score 0):

just add `scroll="false"` to your `<ion-content scroll="false">`
and also please check in controller to add this :

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```